# Call predicate again if a statement fails

Tags: prolog, predicate

I am fairly a beginner new to Prolog. Is it possible for me to continue execution of the predicate if a statement evaluates to true inside? Here is my snippet of code:

```
%Ylist contains: [1,2,3]
validatemove(_,[],_). % goal if Ylist is empty

validatemove(X, [Y1|Ylist], Node) :-
    X \= 0,     % if X is 0, return false
    Y1 \= 0,    % if Y1 is 0, do not execute rest of code,
                % call validatemove(X, Ylist, Node) again
    Some predicates here,
    ....,
    validatemove(X, Ylist, Newnode).
```

I am struggling to come up with something like this. Either way, I want to iterate over all the values given in `Ylist`. What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for the *if-then-else* control construct. Maybe something like:

```
%Ylist contains: [1,2,3]

validate_move([], _, _). % goal if Ylist is empty

validate_move([Y| Ys], X, Node) :-
    X =\= 0,
    % if X is 0, return false
    (  Y =:= 0 ->
       validate_move(Ys, X, Node)
    ;  % Some predicates here,
       validate_move(Ys, X, NewNode)
    ).
```

Note that, assuming your list is known when the predicate is called, is best to move it to the first argument to take advantage of Prolog first-argument indexing (which is implemented by most of the systems). You seem to be comparing integers, so use arithmetic comparison predicates instead of unification predicates. Also, is good Prolog programming style to use underscores to separate words in atoms and also usual to use CamelCase only for variables.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something similar as specified, I am able to call `validatemove`, but it does not chops off the `head` of the list for the next call? This is my call:  `Redo: (10) validatemove([1, 2, 3], 1, [3, [1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]) ? creep`. It should be  `Redo: (10) validatemove([2, 3], 1, [3, [1, 0, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]) ? creep`.

Comment: Ok, now I am able to make a valid call to `validatemove` if `Y` is evaluated to 0. But when `Y` is not equal to 0, it does not execute the rest of the code?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. In my answer, both recursive calls to the `validate_move /3` predicate take the tail of the list. Are you missing a *third*  clause in your code for the predicate?

Comment: Is it possible for me to execute some predicates before calling `validate_move/3` when `Y` is not equal to 0?

Comment: Just replace the comment "% Some predicates here," with whatever you want to call. I assume those predicates will calculate `NewNode` from `Node`?

Comment: Just a follow up question, for my next iteration, `X =\= 0` evaluates to `false`. As expected, the recursion should unfold, but the code behaves in an unexpected way. And some code block in `;  % Some predicates here,` section starts executing. Until it unfolds completely (losing my state) and return false in the end.. Can you tell me what goes wrong there? And how to retain the state of the values and return as it is?